# Prism for Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

### Prism for Windows phone 8

I have developed an application in C#/XAML for windows 8 using prism .I want to implement the same pattern in my windows phone 8 application also. Which prism library can I use???

Comment: [PRISM](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/prism)? `:P`

Answer (score 1):

A pre-release version is available on NuGet here: http://nuget.org/packages/PortablePrism.WP8/

> Microsoft PRISM 4.1 ported to Portable Class Library and
>   Microsoft.Composition.
>
> Namespaces are not changed for convenience.
>
> To install Portable PRISM - Windows Phone 8, run the following command
>   in the Package Manager Console
>
> **PM> Install-Package PortablePrism.WP8 -Pre**

Comment: This package is not official. It's not related to Microsoft in any way.

Comment: Is there any example on how to create a new WP8 project from scratch available for that lib?

Answer (score 1):

please try this : https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com

The Prism library and AdventureWorks Shopper RI demonstrate how to create Windows Store apps using C# and XAML for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Blaine Wastell (one of the prism dev team) on Twitter who said that the guys would be looking to start development on this in February or March.

https://twitter.com/blainewastell/status/423927087993331714